# Efficient multichoice with complex structures

Tags: ruby

I am making an old-school "choose your own adventure" game. For each selection's structure, I've come up with code that looks like this:

```
a1 = gets.chomp
prompt = "> "

puts "1. Left | 2. Right. | 3. Straight"
print prompt

while a1 = gets.chomp
  case a1
  when "1"
    puts "Insert bad choice descriptor"
    break
  when "2"
    puts "Stats-based chance descriptor"
    break
  when "3"
    puts "Correct descriptor, lead into next logical timeline"
    break
  else
    puts "Invalid input!"
    print prompt
  end
```

With many choices with a bunch of potential future lines, this can quickly become a clusterfuzzle of order and maintenance.

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: What are the `break`s for? Can you show the loop you are breaking out of? The context might be important.

Comment: Ahh thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't removed the breaks from the test file before I uploaded here.

Edit: The original intent was to stop the loop process that was triggered in the case of invalid input.

What would you like to know context-wise? The idea is that a user makes decisions that progressively move through a storyline.

Comment: I propose to use YAML to configure and describe your non-liner storyline.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways you could reduce repetition in your code somewhat.

**Use a `case` statement**

```
puts "1. Left | 2. Right. | 3. Straight"

loop do
  n = gets.chomp
  print "> " +
  case n 
  when '1'
    "Insert bad choice descriptor"
  when '2'
    "Stats-based chance descriptor"
  when '3'
    "Correct descriptor, lead into next logical timeline"
  else
    "Invalid input!"
  end
  puts
  break if ['1','2','3'].include?(n)
end
```

[Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) is commonly used for loops There are two ways to break out of such loops. One, as used here, is to use the keyword `break`. The other is to raise a `StopIteration` exception. `loop` handles that by breaking out of the loop (see the doc for `loop`).<sup>1</sup>.

Note that I've used [Kernel#print](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-print) rather than [Kernel#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) so the user's input will be typed immediately following `"> "`, on the same line. `print` prints the string formed by combining `"> "` with the string returned by the `case` statement. `puts` near the end adds a newline to the line just displayed.

**Use a hash**

```
h = { "1"=>"Insert bad choice descriptor", "2"=>"Stats-based chance descriptor",
      "3"=>"Correct descriptor, lead into next logical timeline" }

puts "1. Left | 2. Right. | 3. Straight"

loop do
  n = gets.chomp
  print "> #{ h.fetch(n, "Invalid input!") }"
  puts
  break if ['1','2','3'].include?(n)
end
```

See [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch), especially for the explanation of the significance of its (optional) second argument.

A variant of this is to add the statement:

```
h.default = "Invalid input!"
```

and replace the `print` line with<sup>3</sup>:

```
print "> #{ h[n] }"
```

Note that `gets.chomp` returns a string, which is always a *truthy value*<sup>2</sup> (even an empty string). Your statement, `while a1 = gets.chomp`, will therefore never terminate the loop.

<sup>1 Enumerators (instances of the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html)) raise a *StopIteration* exception when they have generated their last value and are asked to generate another one. That's how the following works:</sup>

```
enum = [1,2,3].to_enum
   #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>
loop do
  puts enum.next
end
```

<sup>which prints `"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"` (on separate lines).</sup>

<sup>2 A *truthy value* is any Ruby object other than `nil` or `false`. They evaluate `true` in logical expressions (e.g, `"" ? 'cat' : 'dog'` returns `'cat'`. *Falsy values* are `nil` and `false`. They evaluate `false` in logical expressions.</sup>

<sup>3 See [Hash#default](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D).</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your indepth reply, that helps out a ton! :) +1

Comment: I’m happy to be of help.